# Can' include gem in my code

Tags: ruby

I don't get why my script can't find the gem that I just installed. Here is the code of main.rb

```
require 'exifr'
```

At this point I get

```
LoadError: no such file to load — exifr
```

error message

Here is the output of

```
gem environment

GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
```

When I do

```
ls /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/exifr-1.1.3/bin/exifr
```

I get

```
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/exifr-1.1.3/bin/exifr
```

So the gem is in that location.
I'm running Mac OS Lion.
What I do wrong ?

//EDIT

```
gem list exifr

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

exifr (1.1.3)

1.9.3-p194 :001 > require 'exifr'
 => true
```

Comment: Probably need to `require 'rubygems'` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when running ruby 1.9 you do not have to require rubygems anymore, so this should not be an issue.

looking at the `bin` directory is not of any use, cause the gems usually live in `lib`.

if you do a `gem list exifr` your installed gem should print out like

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

exifr (1.1.3)
```

the next step would be to try it out via the ruby REPL

```
$ irb
1.9.3p125 :001 > require "exifr"
 => true 
1.9.3p125 :002 > exit
```

this indicates that everything is installed fine.

Comment: so your gem is installed and can be required properly. the only thing left is your ruby. what does ```which ruby``` gives you?

Comment: /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby

Comment: how are you executing your main.rb file?

Comment: Now I get what I miss. I put !#/usr/bin/ruby instead of #!/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby at the beginning of the file.

Comment: to be compatible, you should use ```env``` in your shebang ```#!/usr/bin/env ruby```

Comment: With #!/usr/bin/env ruby instead of #!/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby I get no such file to load — exifr

Comment: Points to /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby